# How to restore from a backup of a very old version of DB2 (version 6.1 backup)?

Tags: db2, backup, restore

I am helping a client with some legacy application that is still running DB2 6.1 on Windows 2000! I am helping them migrate to newer software/hardware infrastructure.

- I have a backup of the DB2 6.1 database on Windows 2000.
- As a first step I want to restore a new database image from this backup on a
  newer version of DB2.
- The Latest version of DB2 does not support restoring from a v6.1
  backup.

  Can I find a relatively new version of DB2 that will restore a v6.1 DB2
  backup?

  Any insight into options available for my scenario are appreciated.

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade via restore is usually supported for databases two versions down, so to move from DB2 6.1 to DB2 10.1 (current today) you'd need to move to DB2 8.2 first, then to DB2 9.5, then to DB2 10.1. There are many things that have changed between all these versions, so it's very unlikely that the process will be smooth. Your best option would be to extract the database DDL statements and data, then create a new DB2 10.1 database and load data into it.

Comment: ++ to extracting DDL and data and recreating. Probably less hassle than multiple upgrades.